# What does () accomplish in a subroutine definition in Perl?

Tags: perl, prototype, definition, subroutine

The following code is lifted directly from the source of the Tie::File module.  What do the empty parentheses accomplish in the definition of O_ACCMODE in this context?  I know what subroutine prototypes are used for, but this usage doesn't seem to relate to that.

```
use Fcntl 'O_CREAT', 'O_RDWR', 'LOCK_EX', 'LOCK_SH', 'O_WRONLY', 'O_RDONLY';
sub O_ACCMODE () { O_RDONLY | O_RDWR | O_WRONLY }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions) on the topic of constant functions:

> Functions with a prototype of () are
>   potential candidates for inlining

Answer (score 12):

It also tells the parser that `O_ACCMODE` doesn't take an argument under any condition (except `&O_ACCMODE()` which you will likely never have to think about). This makes it behave like most people expect a constant to.

As a quick example, in:

```
sub FOO { 1 }
sub BAR { 2 }

print FOO + BAR;
```

the final line parses as `print FOO(+BAR())` and the value printed is 1, because when a prototypeless sub is called without parens it tries to act like a listop and slurp terms as far right as it can.

In:

```
sub FOO () { 1 }
sub BAR () { 2 }

print FOO + BAR;
```

The final line parses as `print FOO() + BAR()` and the value printed is 3, because the `()` prototype tells the parser that no arguments to `FOO` are expected or valid.

Answer (score 7):

The prototype of `()` makes the subroutine eligible for inlining. This is used by the `constant` pragma, for example.

See [Constant Functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Constant-Functions) in perlsub.